# Import error with JOGL and NEWT

Tags: java, opengl, jogl

I am trying to get JOGL to run on my Raspberry Pi, as Java2D simply wasn't cutting it.  I'm fairly familiar with OpenGL and graphics pipelines, but my Java is a bit rusty.  I am using Eclipse.

So, I tried first to use swing components with a GLCanvas.  Worked great on windows, but I got the following error on the Pi:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: 
javax.media.nativewindow.DefaultGraphicsConfiguration cannot be cast to   
com.jogamp.nativewindow.awt.AWTGraphicsConfiguration 
at javax.media.opengl.awt.GLCanvas chooseGraphicsConfiguration(GLCanvas.java:1096)
```

So, I read somewhere that JOGL will only work in the Pi with NEWT.  So, I tried to follow a tutorial or two, but as soon as I add the import line for com.jogamp.newt.opengl.GLWindow, it gives the following build errors:

```
The type com.jogamp.common.util.locks.RecursiveLock cannot be resolved. 
It is indirectly referenced from required .class
```

or

```
The type com.jogamp.common.type.WriteCloneable cannot be resolved. 
It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
```

I have both gluegen-rt.jar and jogl-all.jar included.  What am I missing?  I've been searching for hours and it's driving me mad.

Comment: I do now get the AWTGraphicsConfiguration if I try to use AWT and a glError 0x500 (IIRC) when using the NEWT method on raspbian. Even when using the Broadcom driver command option.
Did you find any solution to this? Btw: I "simply" imported ALL jars to not get the ClassNotFound errors and tried the NEWT Gears example.

Comment: You should write on the forum if you still didnt solve, there were some advancing with the Raspberry